# How to apply style to disabled form button on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the code below, I want to apply a shake effect on the `Sign-Up` button whenever the user clicks it and there's errors in the input values. (password/ mail mismatch)

The problem I'm having is that I disable the button in the js code if the inputs are wrong and thus can't use **click** or **onclick**.

How can I achieve that?

```js
let mailOK = false;
let passOK = false;
$("#mailSignupInput, #mailConfirmInput").keyup
(
    () => {
        let mail1 = $("#mailSignupInput")
        let mail2 = $("#mailConfirmInput")

        if (!(mail1.val() === mail2.val())) {
            document.getElementById("mailMatch").style.display=""
            mail1.css({borderColor: "red",
                borderWidth: "3px",
                borderStyle:"solid"})
            mail2.css({borderColor: "red",
                borderWidth: "3px",
                borderStyle:"solid"})

            mailOK = false
        }
        else if (mail1.val()=== mail2.val()) {
            document.getElementById("mailMatch").style.display="none"
            mail1.css({borderWidth : "0px"})
            mail2.css({borderWidth : "0px"})
            mailOK = true
        }
    }
)

$("#passSignupInput, #passConfirmInput").keyup
(
    () => {
        let pass1 = $("#passSignupInput")
        let pass2 = $("#passConfirmInput")

        if (!(pass1.val() === pass2.val())) {
            document.getElementById("passMatch").style.display=""
            pass1.css({borderColor: "red",
                borderWidth: "3px",
                borderStyle:"solid"})
            pass2.css({borderColor: "red",
                borderWidth: "3px",
                borderStyle:"solid"})

            passOK = false
        }
        else if (pass1.val()=== pass2.val()){
            document.getElementById("passMatch").style.display="none"
            pass1.css({borderWidth : "0px"})
            pass2.css({borderWidth : "0px"})
            passOK = true
        }
    }
)

setInterval(validateSignup, 10)
function validateSignup() {
    document.getElementById("submitSignup").disabled = !(passOK === true && mailOK === true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="signupForm" class="form" action="" method="post">
                    <!--Mail Signup Section-->
                    <div id="mailDiv">
                        <!--Mail Input-->
                        <label id="mailLabel" for="mailSignupInput">E-Mail:</label>
                        <br>
                        <input id="mailSignupInput" class="textInput" type="text" name="username"
                               placeholder="mail@example.com" autocomplete="off">
                        <br>
                        
                        <!--Confirm Mail Input-->
                        <br>
                        <label id="mailLabel" for="mailConfirmInput">Confirm E-Mail:</label>
                        <br>
                        <input id="mailConfirmInput" class="textInput" type="text" name="username"
                               placeholder="mail@example.com" autocomplete="off">
                        <br>
                        <span style="display: none; color: red" id = "mailMatch">Email values do not match</span>
                        <br>
                        <span style="display: none; color: red" id = "mailValid">Email is not valid</span>
                    
                    </div>
                    
                    <br>
                    
                    <!--Password Signup Section-->
                    <div id="passDiv">
                        <!--Password Input-->
                        <label id="passLabel" for="passSignupInput">Password:</label>
                        <br>
                        <input id="passSignupInput" class="textInput" type="password" name="pass" autocomplete="off">
                        <br>
                        
                        <!--Confirm Password Input-->
                        <br>
                        <label id="passLabel" for="passConfirmInput">Confirm Password:</label>
                        <br>
                        <input id="passConfirmInput" class="textInput" type="password" name="pass" autocomplete="off">
                        <br>
                        <span style="display: none; color: red" id = "passMatch">Passwords do not match</span>
                    </div>
                    
                    <br>
                    
                    <!--Signup Button Section-->
                    <div id="buttonDiv">
                        <input id="submitSignup" class="buttonInput" type="submit" value="SIGN-UP">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: I have no idea what this should be good for because disabling the button should be good enough to tell the user he has forgotten to fill out user or password. but if you really want to achieve this, just put a transparent div over the button and add a click handler to it

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm listening for the `invalid` event on the two input elements. If one of them is invalid the function `notvalid()` will be called and it will add the class name "shake" to the button. The button shakes and when the animation is done the class name is removed again.

So, in this example I'm overruling the default behavior on the required input elements. It is up to you to decide if this is a good idea. Instead of shaking the button you could also alert the user in other ways -- displaying a text, style the input elements, make an alert box etc.

```js
const notvalid = target => {
  target.form.button.classList.add('shake');
};

document.forms.form01.button.addEventListener('animationend', e => {
  e.target.classList.remove('shake');
});

document.forms.form01.user.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  notvalid(e.target);
});

document.forms.form01.password.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  notvalid(e.target);
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('everything is ok');
});
```

```css
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
}

.shake {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 5;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input type="text" name="user" required/>
  <input type="password" name="password" required/>
  <button name="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```